Wireless display for raspberry pi 0w
I am wondering how to connect raspberry pi 0w to a display wirelessly (to be more specific via wi-fi).
the devices which I have are

raspberry pi 0w
waveshare 7.9inch display

any pointers will be good for me,
I suspect I need to connect some peripheral device to both pi and display
so that they communicate display signals wirelessly.
OR
pi already have wi-fi so I need to connect some peripheral device to display so that pi broadcasts signals to display over wi-fo

You can use this commercial VNC or this free VNC (Virtual Network Console) application over any network including WIFI to display a computer's console on another computer's screen. Or you might try this Raspberry Pi Beta Version Connect which sounds to be similar.
However this requires the remote screen to be connected to a computer. Ironically, one of the cheapest ways of doing this is with yet another Raspberry Pi.
If using WIFI is not necessary, there are COTS wireless HDMI solutions that are available.

Note that there are a variety of VNC and similar software available to do this and not all of them are paid commercial.  I've used nomachine, it works well and is fairly simple.


I need to connect some peripheral device to both pi and display

Without using another computer (as per st2000's answer), you will need a
wireless HDMI transmitter/receiver pair, since the screen only has an HDMI input.  This will probably be more reliable and it will certainly be much easier to set up as no software needs to be installed or configured by you, but it may cost a bit more.
